# Postfix Mail not sending for gmail, yahoo, but working in third party mails like Mailinator -- Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: php, email, postfix

I use Ubuntu for the first time. 
I have included mail functionality for my application, for which I am using **postfix**. Also I used **phpMailer** for sending mails.
I cannot receive mail for gmail, outlook, yahoo but i am able to receive mails for third party mails like mailinator.com

advance thanks for all.

Comment: Welcome Magnil to askubuntu! Please edit your post and include what version of Ubuntu you are using. Further post some error output or warnings you got, and how did you configured postfix.

Comment: @abu_bua i have mentioned the version please have a look

Comment: no idea on that. am  new to this project they already configured and worked fine but now mail not sending

Comment: how check the error log  or how to debug its working or not

Comment: Please include the relevant logs from `/var/log/mail.err` and `/var/log/mail.warn`., and how you have configured postfix. Probably the mail is rejected by spam policies on the receiving end.

Comment: i could not able to edit/view /var/log/mail.log from filezilla . it show permission denied issue

Comment: previous programmer configured postfix. i am new to ubuntu as well as this project

Comment: /var/log/mail.log: open for read: permission denied
Error: File transfer failed  

this error i am getting while access the mail.log file